# Installing libboost 1.48 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boost

I want to install libboost 1.48 on my ubuntu 14.04.When I issued the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev-all
```

It installed the latest libboost which is not my requirement so I have now downloaded the libboost 1.48 on my system. My Question is that is there way to install libboost 1.48 on ubuntu 14.04?

**update**

When I try to install it I got following message

[image]

Comment: The purpose of `libboost-all-dev` packages is to install all libboost[version]. No content in libboost-all-dev packages. The libboost[name]1.48.0 packages http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=libboost → Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Thanx.But then How would I use 1.48 or put it more precisely make it default for compiling my code with libboost?

Comment: Your code will probably choose the latest boost version : You may have to remove libboost-[name]1.54-dev, libboost-[name]1.55-dev packages.

Comment: But there are so many other versions with that line 1.49,1.54 etc etc....what about them.Should I also need to uninstall them?

Comment: @NaseerAhmed Perhaps aspects of this answer might be useful to you: http://askubuntu.com/a/801552/57576